# Sharepoint 2016 - Internal Server Error Exception clicking on subsites

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, upgrade

I upgraded SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2016.  I have three environments for SharePoint 2016: DEV, QA and PROD.  I moved the service application db's and one content db to DEV, added service application db's, mounted content db's and no issues loading subsites.  Same behavior in QA.  Clicking on subsites in prod environment generates:

Sorry, something went wrong
Internal server error exception:
Technical Details

PROD Environment: 1 App Server, 1 Web Server, 1 SQL Server, claims based authentication

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: You’ll need to add much more detail in order for anyone to help you.  What were the technical details?  Are there any event log entries for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened dev tools in Edge and Chrome, loaded subsites-no errors displayed in dev tools.  I reviewed the ULS logs but I didn't see any errors.

Searching other web app site collections returned "Sorry, something went wrong" error as well.  I recreated SSA and added the new web app url to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0.  Internal server error exception still appeared.

Not sure if recreating SSA, adding web application url to the registry key above and waiting awhile fixed it but today subsites load without error.